# increasing memory while creating index in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have already 300GB data into table.
I want to add indexing to a perticlar column but when adding index on a column then increase the memory of drive(or increase the size of ibdata file).
This process is apply to another table but memory is not increase.

below is query to add indexing,
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (column)

Answer (score 0):

In general, *the amount of space needed for the index tables, varies between about 50% of the original text volume and 200%.*

Generally, the larger the total amount of text, the smaller the overhead, but many small records will use more overhead than fewer large records. Also, clean data (such as published text) will require less overhead than dirty data such as emails or discussion notes, since the dirty data is likely to include many unique words from spellings mistakes  and abbreviations.

So,the data type and content of the column also matters.

Hope this will help you a bit..!!

Comment: datatype of column is varchar(900)

Comment: Hmm.. Index takes physical memory and It also depends on total number of unique records you have in that column. That is the reason it takes for disk space.

Comment: Sir all records are unique records.it takes 50% disk space of data.I think it shouldn't take more space.